# Find n longest words in string efficiently

Tags: javascript, string, sorting, charactercount

We can find the longest word in a string like this:

```
str.split(" ").sort(function(a, b) {return b.length - a.length})[0];
```

How can one find the top n longest words efficiently? For example, how can I extract the top 3 longest words, not just *the* longest?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just replace the `[0]` with, say some notation to slice out the first 3 items in the sorted array? I'm rusty with JS, but in Python it would be `[:3]`. I think it's `.slice(0, 3)`?

Comment: As Arya said, you can slice and get 'n' words:
Example:

str.split(" ").sort(function(a, b) {return b.length - a.length}).slice(0,3)

Comment: With a top n heap sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array#slice`.

```
str.split(" ").sort(function(a, b) {return b.length - a.length}).slice(0,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a list, ranked from top to bottom?  That's what sorting is for.  You already have the list, just remove the `[0]` from the end of the line because that means "access the first item of the list", and replace it with, say, `slice(0, 3)` to get the last 3 items.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about getting unique words, you can use the `slice` method.

```
const n = 3
const longestWords = str.split(" ").sort(function(a, b) {return b.length - a.length}).slice(0, n)
```

But if the same word appeared multiple times, you might get it multiple times in the output. For instance, "foo bar fooy fooy" would result in `['fooy', 'fooy', 'bar']`.

To eliminate this issue, convert the initial array into a set first.

```js
const str = 'foo bar fooy fooy'
const n = 2
const words = str.split(" ")
const uniqueWords = [...new Set(words)]
const longestWords = uniqueWords.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length).slice(0, n)
console.log(longestWords)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [`.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) returns **all** the elements, sorted in your order, you can just loop of the result.

Remove the `[0]` part of your code to keep all elements.

```js
const string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.';
const counted = string.split(' ').sort(function(a, b) {return b.length - a.length});

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   console.log(i, counted[i]);
}
```